# Fastlane export ipa fail

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, fastlane

I am trying to use Fastlane to do a CI job for generate iPA file.
The archived file are generated successfully. But for the export part I can't make it work.

The error is like:

```
        error: exportArchive: test1.framework does not support provisioning profiles.
        
        Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=10 "test1.framework does 
not support provisioning profiles." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, 
    NSLocalizedDescription= test1.framework does not support provisioning profiles.,
     NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion= test1.framework does not 
support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile PROFILE_TEST1 has been manually specified. 
Remove this item from the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
```

I can understand the error, the framework doesn't support the profile. The thing is how could I remove it?

Here is my **Fastfile**

```
lane :beta do |options|

    name = get_provisioning_profile(
      force: false,
      app_identifier: "com.xxx.test1",
      filename: "PROFILE_test1.mobileprovision")
    

    update_app_identifier(
      xcodeproj: "MyProject.xcodeproj",
      plist_path: "./mainInfo.plist", 
      app_identifier: "com.xxx.test1"
    )


    //Is this update_project_provisioning issue? I thought this line 
    //only setup my com.xxx.test1 to profile PROFILE_TEST1, correct?

    update_project_provisioning(xcodeproj: "MyProject.xcodeproj")



    build_app(
      workspace: "MyProject.xcworkspace", 
      output_directory: "./OutputFile",
      xcconfig: xcconfigPath,
        export_method: "enterprise",
        scheme: "MyProject"
      )

  end
```

I have tried to set the **export_options** -> **provisioningProfiles** to empty, but still the same error.

```
build_app(
          workspace: "MyProject.xcworkspace", 
          output_directory: "./OutputFile",
          xcconfig: xcconfigPath,
            export_method: "enterprise",
            scheme: "MyProject",
          export_options: {
             provisioningProfiles: {
               "com.xxx.framework1" => "",
               "com.xxx.framework2" => "",
             }
          })
```

**EDIT**

With this setup:

```
build_app(
          workspace: "MyProject.xcworkspace", 
          output_directory: "./OutputFile",
          xcconfig: xcconfigPath,
            export_method: "enterprise",
            scheme: "MyProject"
          )
```

The output is:

```
: ▸ Archive Succeeded
[19:03:09]: Generated plist file with the following values:
[19:03:09]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
[19:03:09]: ▸ {
[19:03:09]: ▸   "provisioningProfiles": {
[19:03:09]: ▸     "com.xxx/test1": "PROFILE_TEST1"
[19:03:09]: ▸   },
[19:03:09]: ▸   "method": "enterprise",
[19:03:09]: ▸   "signingStyle": "manual"
[19:03:09]: ▸ }
[19:03:09]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
```

Any part on my Fastfile setup wrong?

How could I set to the profile **None** for the framework target?
Appreciate for any help?

**EDIT**

If I remove `xcconfig` option from `build_app` it works correct. If set it prompt the errors above.